# Python function return type does not match fortran subroutine declartion type

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I have some Python codes as below , `spherical.py`:

```
...
import f_utils

# (r, theta, phi)
class spherical_utilities(object):
    def __init__(self, ng, n, lab):
        self.n = n
        self.ng = ng
        self.set_ngauss()
        self.set_funcs_ang()
        self.set_all_layers(lab)

    def set_ngauss(self):
        k, w = ps_roots(self.ng)
        self.knots, self.weights = k * pi, w * pi
        self.thetas = self.knots
        self.sint = sin(self.thetas)
        self.cost = cos(self.thetas)
        self.tgt = tan(self.thetas)
        self.ctgt = 1 / self.tgt

    def set_funcs_ang(self):
        P = array([special.lpmn(self.n, self.n, ct) for ct in self.cost])
        self.data_Ang, self.data_Angd = P[:, 0, :, :], P[:, 1, :, :]

    def set_all_layers(self, lab):
        self.data_layers = [0]
        for bnd in lab.boundaries():
            r, rd, rdd = bnd.shape.R(self.knots)
            rdr = rd / r
            r2rd2 = r ** 2 + rd ** 2
            Rad = [0, {}, {}]
            Radd = [0, {}, {}]
            kis = [0, bnd.k1, bnd.k2]
            for i in [1, 2]:
                krs = kis[i] * r
                JY = array([special.sph_jnyn(self.n, kr) for kr in krs])[:, :, :]
                Rad[i] = {'j': JY[:, 0, :], 'h': JY[:, 0, :] + 1j * JY[:, 2, :]}
                Radd[i] = {'j': JY[:, 1, :], 'h': JY[:, 1, :] + 1j * JY[:, 3, :]}

            self.data_layers.append({'ki': kis,\
                                     'r': r,\
                                     'rd': rd,\
                                     'rdd': rdd,\
                                     'rdr': rdr,\
                                     'r2rd2': r2rd2,\
                                     'Rad': Rad,\
                                     'Radd': Radd})
...

def mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, jh1, jh2, e12, e21):
    k1 = C.ki[1]
    k2 = C.ki[2]
    Rad1 = C.Rad(m, jh1, 1)
    Radd1 = C.Radd(m, jh1, 1)
    Rad2 = C.Rad(m, jh2, 2)
    Radd2 = C.Radd(m, jh2, 2)
    Angm = C.Ang(m)
    Angmd = C.Angd(m)
    return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm, Angmd,\
                         C.r, C.rd, C.sint, C.cost, k1, k2, e12, C.weights)
```

**and in other file , `methods.py`:**

```
...
import spherical
...
C = spherical.spherical_utilities(ng, n, lab)
... 
def ebcm_bnd_system(C, m, bnd, axisymm=False):
    lay = bnd.layer_no
    C.set_layer_no(lay)
    # Axisymmetric part
    if axisymm:
        Ajjtm = spherical.mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, 'j', 'j', bnd.e12, bnd.e21)
...    
def methods_factory(meth_bnd_system):

...    

ebcm = methods_factory(ebcm_bnd_system)
...
```

And have some fortran corresponding codes as below , in `f_utils.for` :

```
SUBROUTINE axitm (NG,NN,Rad1,Radd1,Rad2,Radd2,Ang,Angd,
     &                        Rs,Rsd,SinT,CosT,k1,k2,ep12,w,O)
      implicit none
      INTEGER NG,NN
      COMPLEX*16 Rad1(NG,NN),Radd1(NG,NN),Rad2(NG,NN),Radd2(NG,NN)
      COMPLEX*16 Ang(NG,NN), Angd(NG,NN)
      COMPLEX*16 k1,k2,ep12
      REAL*8     SinT(NG),CosT(NG), Rs(NG),Rsd(NG)
      COMPLEX*16 O(NN,NN)
      COMPLEX*16 w(NG)
cf2py intent(out) O
cf2py intent(hide) NG,NN
      integer l,n,k
      complex*16 coef, j1,jd1,j2,jd2,pl,pdl,pn,pdn
      real*8 sn,cs,r,rd
      complex*16 fun1

      DO l=1,NN
      DO n=1,NN
        O(l,n)=0d0
      ENDDO
      ENDDO

      DO k=1,NG
      r  = Rs(k)
      rd = Rsd(k)
      cs = CosT(k)
      sn = SinT(k)

      DO l=1,NN
      DO n=1,NN

      j1  = Rad1(k,l)
      jd1 = Radd1(k,l)
      j2  = Rad2(k,n)
      jd2 = Radd2(k,n)
      pl  = Ang(k,l)
      pdl = Angd(k,l)
      pn  = Ang(k,n)
      pdn = Angd(k,n)

      fun1 = k1**2 * r**2 * ( jd1 * j2 -
     & ep12 * k2/k1 * j1 * jd2) *
     & pl * pn * sn
     & + k1 * rd * sn**2 * (pdl * pn - ep12*
     & pl * pdn) * j1 * j2
     & - (ep12 - 1) * (k1 * r * sn - k1 * rd * cs) *
     & j1 * j2 * pl * pn

      O(l,n) = O(l,n) + fun1*w(k)

      ENDDO
      ENDDO
      ENDDO

      DO l=1,NN
       coef = (0d0,1d0) * (2d0 * l + 1) / (2 * l * (l+1))
      DO n=1,NN
       O(l,n) = O(l,n) * coef
      ENDDO
      ENDDO

      end
```

For Python :

```
  return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm, Angmd,\
                          C.r, C.rd, C.sint, C.cost, k1, k2, e12, C.weights)
```

For fortran :

```
SUBROUTINE axitm (NG,NN,Rad1,Radd1,Rad2,Radd2,Ang,Angd,
      &                        Rs,Rsd,SinT,CosT,k1,k2,ep12,w,O)
```

I don't want to edit my fortran and Python original files.

When I run normally the `spherical.py` I get this error :

> ValueError: 0-th dimension must be fixed to 1 but got 200

For this line of code in Python:

```
return f_utils.axitm(Rad1, Radd1, Rad2, Radd2, Angm, Angmd,\
                          C.r, C.rd, C.sint, C.cost, k1, k2, e12, C.weights)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use tags that people ctually follow, so that they can see your question. Do not overspecify the versions in the tag unless you ask for some specific point of that version. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions and add a specific version where necessary (not here).

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work."? Do not say this, say the actual error you get. It is normal for f2py to move an output subroutine argument and use it as a return value of the Python function. The array sizes variables `N` are determined from the actual array dimensions you pass in Python.

Comment: Really not my field... but shouldn't be there where to get NG and NN from? Something like `Cf2py integer intent(hide),depend(Ang) :: NG=shape(Ang,0), NN=shape(Ang,1)`?

Comment: Your Python code is very incomplete, please supply a full [mcve] so that the code can be tested.I do not see any problem in the Fortran code. And do state what kind of problems you get. I see more code in some of your links but it is full of *"...after some modification..."* so it is not clear at all which actual code we should test.

Comment: Don't just say "this makes error". Show a code that can be tested and show the actual error it makes.

Comment: The code you link is some library. So how do you use the library. Which actual code should we run to get the error you speak about? There must be some your own code you actually run.

Comment: Ok. I will show testable codes and actual error as soon as possible .but which useable library ,which error and my own code should I clarify ?

Comment: The point is there should be **no reason** to pass those two parameters. Without seeing the error happenning in the actual code and uderstanding it we can't really help you. We could tell you to remove the hide attribute, but will that solve your *actual* problem? I doubt so. BTW, see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Comment: In the test.py there is no reference to f_utils and no reference to axitm or the Fortran subroutine. Really, this does not lead anywhere. I do not think anyone can help you because you failed to give us the real problem we can analyze. You must give us the **complete** and **minimal** code that we can run and we can see the error.

Comment: Reference to f_utils and to axitm are in https://github.com/ScattPy/scikits.scattpy/blob/master/scikits/scattpy/spherical.py . test.py only call spherical.py code.

Comment: The point of a [mcve] is that t is self-contained and can be included within the question itself. We do not even know if tje ScattPy is your code.  The latest commit is 7 years ago. Have you really been solving this error for 7 years or are you actually having the error in some other code?

Comment: No, I try to compile old codes because I need them. I am not sure the error was be in old version or not. I think they weren't .but some reversion is needed.
As I found `NG`,`NN` get value from dimension of array `Rad1` and so far. It means not necessary to assign value to  `NG`,`NN`, they got that automatically .So I must to define other arguments such as `Rad1,Radd1,Rad2,Radd2,Ang,Angd` and so far. Is it right?

Comment: So if you describe it more, it would be the answer of my main question as `Python function return type does not match fortran subroutine declartion type`

Comment: So ,the next level is that it would be the problem in Python code with `def mat_ebcm_axi_tm(C, m, jh1, jh2, e12, e21):`

Comment: I do not really know which problem now. This question with so many edits is a complete mess now. I suggest rewriting it completely and clearly state which exact code you are running,which output it creates and point out the errors. Do ot use UPDATE1, UPDATE2... Just rewrite it to a state that would be as clear as possible.

Comment: I have a question. Should rad1 , radd1 , rad2, radd2 , ang , angd  and others in fortran source have the same size as they set the hide NG , NN variable? Does it right that size of rad1 ,radd1 and ... Set the hide NN ,NG variable?

Comment: I found the reason of my question. Some documentations are not enough. Must edit question  I will post as soon as possible.but my previous answer 
 I hold it is :Hide fortran variables NG , NNget value from dimension of array Rad1and so far. It means not necessary to assign value to NG,NN they got that automatically .So it must to define other arguments such as Rad1,Radd1,Rad2,Radd2,Ang,Angd and so far.